# Change Styles when Input is checked (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the overlay permanent after input is checked?

I am trying to change the state of the hover, headline and image scaling after the input is checked. Can't get it to work. I am appreciate any help.

**CODEPEN**
https://codepen.io/Ferko/pen/JjEPYbL

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="you-coulmn-hover">
     <input id="testfarben" type="checkbox" name="farbe[]" value="Testfarben">
        <label for="testfarben"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbjZbYv/testpicture.jpg">
          <h4 class="overlay-heading">TESTHEADLINE</h4>
          <div class="overlay-you"></div>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I have tried**

```
.you-coulmn-hover input:checked+h4.overlay-heading {
    color: black;
}
.you-coulmn-hover-1 input:checked+img {
    transform: scale(1.1) !important;
}
.you-coulmn-hover-1 input:checked+.overlay-you {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Just add onclick event to your label with class "checked" toggle and make simple css rules for label.checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.you-coulmn-hover {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: ease-in .5s
}

.you-coulmn-hover img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s
}

.you-coulmn-hover:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}

.you-coulmn-hover:hover .overlay-heading {
    color: #76bce9;
    transition: ease-in-out .5s
}
.overlay-you {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}
.you-coulmn-hover:hover .overlay-you {
    display: block;
}
.overlay-heading {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 21;
}
.you-coulmn-hover input {
    display: none;
}
label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


.you-coulmn-hover input:checked ~ label h4.overlay-heading {
    color: black;
}
.you-coulmn-hover input:checked ~ label img {
    transform: scale(1.1) !important;
}
.you-coulmn-hover input:checked ~ label .overlay-you {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="you-coulmn-hover">
     <input id="testfarben" type="checkbox" name="farbe[]" value="Testfarben">
        <label for="testfarben"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CbjZbYv/testpicture.jpg">
          <h4 class="overlay-heading">TESTHEADLINE</h4>
          <div class="overlay-you"></div>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

or like this one without scripts